# Validation loss is not decreasing less than 0.4 in all architectures

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

For research, I'm working on face anti-spoofing. I have the rose-youtu dataset which spec could be found [here](http://rose1.ntu.edu.sg/datasets/faceLivenessDetection.asp) in details. The problem is no matter what architecture I use for the Model, the validation loss would not be less than ~0.5, Although I tried different architectures (3D CNN, 2D CNN, Fine-tuning, Inception) with different combinations of regularization (Dropout, L1, L2, L1_L2) but the thing is the val_loss will end up at ~0.5 with and when I do evaluation on the test set I get ~0.7 loss and ~0.85% accuracy. Note that there is no overfitting happening, both loss and val_loss are close and converging until they reach ~0.3 which causes the loss to decrease and val_loss fluctuating in the range of ~0.4 0.6.

What is that I'm not considering? Does it mean that the dataset could not be improved more than this?

Comment: "Does it mean that the dataset could not be improved more than this?" In general, yes.

Comment: As I have read their paper, They could reach 7% EER which I think means they have reached better accuracy, at least better than 85% on the test set. BTW they used 3D Convent the same I tried thousands of times
@TheGuywithTheHat

Comment: This sounds like your model is not complex enough and can't capture the data. Try using some very complex model and see if you can over-fit on the training data and then gradually decrease the complexity and observe what the validation error.

Comment: @carobnodrvo what architecture you recommend to use? Is it a good idea to train the VGG16 architecture with my data?

Comment: @MohammadSiavashi Yes, VGG is a first thing I would try.

Comment: @carobnodrvo Thanks I would try that. Does the size of the frames matters? The original size of the Images are very large (camera size images), would it lose significant details if I resize to (256, 256)?

Comment: @carobnodrvo I have a similar stagnation in val_loss (`~0.6`), with AUC score `~0.72` on binary classification task. I have tried VGG16, VGG19, Inception_v3, Resnet50 and some other manual vanilla networks. I've performed excessive hyper-parameter tuning of activations, optimizations, learning rates, batch sizes. What are other ideas you may suggest?

Comment: @bit_scientist Have you tried regularization techniques such as Dropout, Pooling, L1/L2? Also I'd review the dataset labels to see if they are consistent with what you want to achieve.

Comment: @bertslike yes, I have tried them too. My classes are too similar to one another, namely, intra and interclass similarity is high.